# SQL retrieve column from another row in same table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a query that will retrieve employee information from a table that also contains a column named "REPORTS_TO" which is the value of another field called POSITION_NBR (essentially both employees and managers are all in this same table) So I would like to retrieve a row of employee data and then on one of the columns in that row pull in their manager's name which is referenced in another row in the same table.

As an example, employee John Smith has a row with "POSITION_NBR" equal to '1234' and also the column "REPORTS_TO" equal to "5678" On another row, his manager Susie Snowflake has her unique row in the same table with the "POSITION_NBR" equal to "5678" (Same as the "REPORTS_TO" value in the other row). Many employees can share the same manager, and manager's also have a manager.

It's a simple query where I'm doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the same table with a different alias. I'm getting inconsistent data being resulted, this is the query I am using:

```
SELECT 
 A.COMPANY,
 A.DEPTID,
 A.DEPTNAME, 
 A.LOCATION, 
 A.NAME, 
 A.EMPLID, 
 A.REG_TEMP, 
 A.FULL_PART_TIME, 
 A.JOBCODE, 
 A.JOBTITLE, 
 A.SERVICE_DT, 
 A.TERMINATION_DT, 
 A.POSITION_NBR, 
 A.EMPL_STATUS, 
 A.REPORTS_TO,
 AA.NAME AS MANAGER_NAME
FROM PS_EMPLOYEES A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES AA ON AA.POSITION_NBR = A.REPORTS_TO 
--AND AA.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
```

If I remove the un-commented code (to make it active) on the last line I get the correct number of rows, however the last column (AA.NAME AS MANAGER NAME) has all NULL values on every row (should not have any nulls as all employees have a manager assigned). If I keep this line commented out (as written below) then I get about 2,700 additional rows in my results (employee's are duplicated with different manager names)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN rather than LEFT OUTER JOIN. Then use GROUP BY empolyeeID. I think this would give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The format of your query - without the commented part - is correct, and I believe @Gordon_Linoff is correct in that there are duplicate POSITION_NBR values present and this is why you are getting the additional rows.

It doesn't make sense to add in the `AND AA.EMPLID = A.EMPLID` condition because this joins each employee to themselves so you get NULLS for the manager, unless they are their own manager!

Comment: Also, is it definitely the POSITION_NBR field you want to join on and not EMPLID? Looking at the fields in your query I would expect the EMPLID to be the key field that identifies each individual person and therefore the one to join on.

Answer (score 0):

Your description would lead me to suspect that `position_nbr` is duplicated.  Can you try this?

```
select position_nbr, count(*) as cnt
from ps_employees
group by position_nbr
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: The position_nbr is "duplicated" because there are situations where a manager of an employee changes and therefore a new row is added to the database with the same position number for the employee, and a new manager name. I would need to modify the query to look at the latest manager (Max), and not all the historical ones...

Answer (score 0):

You have to left join against the same table.

```
SELECT
 A.NAME
 A.POSITION_NBR
 A.REPORTS_TO
 B.NAME as 'MANAGER'
FROM
 PS_EMPLOYEES A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT NAME, POSITION_NBR FROM PS_EMPLOYEES) B ON B.POSITION_NBR = A.REPORTS_TO
```